# 'ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.h' file not found React Native on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

i integrated react native for my IOS project and encountered this problem, below is my podfile

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'TEST' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!
use_react_native!
pod 'Alamofire'

target 'TESTTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

target 'TESTUITests' do
# Pods for testing
end

end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cisb0.png)

Comment: Please don't add code or error messages as image, use text instead. You can use the image as additional info if you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.